# Distributing 2 times k equals k?

Tags: constants

in my current discrete mathmatics course I have this calculation at the end of a proof:

$$\frac {k(k+1)+2(k+1)}2=\frac {(k+1)(k+2)}2$$

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xga7.png)

I dont under stand why 2*k ends up being k? 
I guessing there is some calculations being abstracted away, can someone please exaplain?

Comment: I think it would be clearer if you let $x=k+1$ and write the left hand as $\frac {kx+2x}2$.  Then, all you are doing is factoring out the $x$ in the numerator.

Comment: nice, but what is was looking for was more what happens inbetween the two, when you distribute 2, why does 2*k become k?

Comment: I don't understand.  $kx+2x=(k+2)x$.  That's just the distributive law.   There is no sense in which $2k$ becomes $k$.

Comment: me neither this is what im wondering about

Answer (score 1):

With colors:
$$\frac{\color{blue}{k}\color{red}{(k+1)}+\color{green}{2}\color{red}{(k+1)}}{2}
=\frac{(\color{blue}{k}+\color{green}{2})\color{red}{(k+1)}}{2}$$
The red part $\color{red}{(k+1)}$ is seen in both terms of the left-hand-side, so can be "moved out" to the right.

Comment: so youre converting two (k + 1) to one, doesnt makr sense?

Comment: @s3j80 Do you (should you) know the distributive law, $(\color{blue}{A}+\color{green}{B})\color{red}{C} = \color{blue}{A}\color{red}{C} + \color{green}{B}\color{red}{C}$?

Comment: no! i had no idea!

Comment: This is something very basic that you have to get familiar with _before_ you follow a discrete mathematics course.

Comment: it just seems odd to me that the c that is to be distributed is behind the parantheses?

Comment: og jeg forstår ikke helt hvad det er du behandler som c'et i den her kontekst

Answer (score 0):

Just factor out the $(k+1)$ term

or if you prefer expand and then factor:

$$\frac {k(k+1)+2(k+1)}2=\frac {k^2+3k+2}2=\frac {(k+1)(k+2)}2$$

Comment: nice, exactly what i was looking for, but where does 3k come from?

Comment: @s3j80: $k(k+1)=k^2+k$ while $2(k+1)=2k+2$ so $k(k+1)+2(k+1)=k^2+k+2k+2=k^2+3k+2$

Comment: Try with $k=10$ as an example:  $\frac{10\times 11 +2\times 11}{2} = \frac{110+22}{2} =\frac{132}{2} = \frac{11\times 12}{2}$

Comment: K * 1 provies k?

Comment: @s3j80: $k \times 1=k$ is certainly true

Comment: all right thank you, that clears up a lot of things

Comment: how does k^2+3k+2 , end up being (k+1)(k+2)?

Comment: @s3j80 Do you know how to expand $(k+1)(k+2)$?

Comment: hmm, i guess not, could you point me in the drection of link?

Comment: @s3j80 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property